# Custom Authorize Attribute additional Param?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

im looking for a way to customize my Authorize Attribute so that i can implement it correctly with my own MembershipProvider.

What i need is to have the IsInRoles(string role, int perm) for example, in other word, i want to have it replace with a new IsinRoles or maybe create another method to archive this result.

Is it possible? or i need to write a different authorize attribute?

Thank you very much for your concern...

PS: im working on ASP.net MVC, so i need to have the [Authorize] filter up and running.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can just add a public property to your custom AuthorizeAttribute.

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Add the allowed roles to this property.
    /// </summary>
    public YourCustomRoles RequiredRole;

    public int YourCustomValue;

    /// <summary>
    /// Checks to see if the user is authenticated and has the
    /// correct role to access a particular view.
    /// </summary>        
    /// <param name="httpContext"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (httpContext == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("httpContext");

        // Make sure the user is authenticated.
        if (httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == false) return false;

        // Can use your properties if needed and do your checks
        bool authorized = DoSomeCustomChecksHere();

        return authorized;
    }
}
```

Usage I think would be (haven't tried it though):

```
[CustomAuthorizeAttribute (RequiredRole=MyCustomRole.Role1 | MyCustomRole.Role2, YourCustomValue=1234)]
```

Comment: is it workable like [Authorize.IsInRole("xxx")] filter before controller? thnx

Comment: thank you for this, just have to implement it to my new authorize class and call it out in controller filter. :)